# Couldn't read from socket input stream

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

I'm currently programming a Chat System using `ServerSocket` and `Socket` with `JFrame` UI. But I'm struggling with reading from Socket Stream.

Here is my Server code:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Socket socket;

        systemStatus.append(displayStatus("Server starts on port: ") + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "\n");
        while (true) {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                String line = in.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    line = in.readLine();
                    systemStatus.append(line);
                }
            }

        }
```

and the send button code at the Client:

```
    log_regButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                String login = log_loginField.getText().trim();
                String pw = log_pwordField.getText().trim();
                out.write(login + "\n" + pw+"\n");
                out.flush();
            }
        });
```

which `systemStatus` is a `JTextArea`. It's suppose to show  text from `JTextField` at Client Frame. But it doesn't. Could anyone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does it show the message: "Server starts on port: "?

Comment: How does your server code get executed?

Comment: Yes it does show the message

Comment: try doing Socket.getInputStream().read(byte[]) in your server and see if you get anything printed out that way. It's possible you are stuck on waiting for a newline character (even though your client seems to be sending data with newline characters)

Comment: Slightly off topic but your server will never accept more than 1 connection, making the first while loop pointless.  Have you verified the client does indeed connect to the server?

Comment: @Phaelaxz Good point. I was thinking that the connection could close and then the server could create another connection, but without a proper try { } catch block, that can't happen

Comment: You're throwing away every odd line. You need to do the append before the second read, not after it.

Comment: @Phaelaxz could you tell me why my server only except 1 connection? I think the while loop helps it except constantly

Comment: @Phaelaxz is wrong, it will accept many connections up to the backlog limit, but it will only *process* them sequentially, because you aren't using a separate thread per connection. So for example the second client won't get any service until the first one disconnects.

Comment: There's nothing breaking it out of the inner loop to ever go back and listen for another connection. While true is just going to continuously look for input from that first connection, serverSocket.accept() will never be reached again.

Comment: @Phaelaxz Obviously, but that doesn't prevent further connections, until the backlog queue is full.

Comment: Isn't that just a backlog of connections attempting to connect?  I thought it didn't actually accept a connection until you call accept

Comment: @Phaelaxz It is a backlog of completed connections. In each case the client's `connect()` call had already returned and the client is able to send or receive.